# Get Unity-like workspace management in Ubuntu Artful 17.10

Tags: workspaces, 17.10, gnome-shell

I upgraded my Ubuntu from 17.04 to 17.10 so now I am using Gnome 3 on Wayland instead of Unity on Compiz. This new setup comes with a rather underwhelming workspace management ("elevator to hell").

**How can I configure Gnome 3 to have it offer more Unity-like workspace behaviour?**

This would include

1. a grid of workspaces (3 columns, 2 rows to be precise);
2. the application windows remaining in the workspace I move them to;
3. miniatures of the workspaces content in the switch modal;
4. workspace switcher showing the overview of all workspaces.

A grid can be achieved partially with the [Workspace Grid shell extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/484/workspace-grid/) and some tweaking using GNOME Tweaks (package `gnome-tweak-tool`).

The windows however get shuffled around the workspaces after the screen saver comes on or the system is suspended. Navigation is also more difficult without any indication of what each workspace contains.

Comment: One non-standard solution is to install MATE DE and select *Mutiny* layout in `mate-tweak`.

Comment: Also you can install `unity` package back.

Answer (score 0):

To an extent, you have to adapt to the working environment you choose to work with.

1) a grid of workspaces (3 columns, 2 rows to be precise);
You already found the Workspace Grid shell extension

2) the application windows remaining in the workspace I move them to;
Using Gnome Tweaks, which is not installed by default in Ubuntu, you can set workspaces to "Static". With dynamic workspaces, workspaces automatically are removed when they are empty, so indeed an application you placed on workspace 3 may end up on workspace 2 or 1 later in the session.

3)miniatures of the workspaces content in the switch modal;
Gnome-shell provides miniatures of the workspaces in the overview when you press Super. By default, however, you have to hover the right side in the overview to make the miniatures visible. You can make sure the workspaces are always expanded with the extension "Always zoom workspaces"

4) workspace switcher showing the overview of all workspaces. 
I do not follow here: in the overview, all workspaces are shown. You may also install a "Workspace switcher" extension that provides a clickable icon on the panel that allows you to switch workspaces from a pull down menu.