# How to get a Grid workspace in Unity 7.5.0?

Tags: unity, 17.10

I'm using Unity 7.5.0 with Ubuntu 17.10,
is there a way to enable Grid workspaces ?

What I have tried:

- Unity Tweak Tool -> Workspace Settings. Changing the number of workspaces here have no effect.
- Compiz config -> Desktop Size. This has no effect either.
- Also, no Appearance menu in Settings screen (it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oxsl4.jpg))

Comment: Have you had a look at [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/967701/783023) ?

Comment: @RobertRiedl Sadly Gnome3 did not work for me. I had to switch to Unity because when I upgraded from 17.04 gdm login screen was broken.

Comment: pity, have you tried to completely remove all gnome packages and install them again ? I'm sure there are some howtos on here for that. Thats not really an answer, but that shouldn't impact your Unity setup.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try your suggestion. I have already uninstalled gnome, so it shouldn't be that hard to purge the remaining packages and install gnome all together again.

Comment: Have you tried [this?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1003335/225694)

Comment: @ElderGeek I have a different Settings screen, no Appearance menu. [here](https://imgur.com/a/B0Uh7) is what it looks like.

Comment: I'm using unity no real issue in 18.04-dev, previously was in 17.10. What your are showing for System Settings is not `unity-control-center`, it's `gnome-control-center` Are you sure you are actually logging into a unity session? (one must reboot after installing unity to get it with gdm3) If so what does `unity-control-center` produce if run in a terminal. Also what does this return?  `env |grep DESKTOP`  1st 3 lines should show unity in them

Comment: @doug I didn't know that. Running `unity-control-center` shows an almost empty settings screen: [image](https://imgur.com/a/Cf56g). Running `env | grep DESKTOP` yields: DESKTOP_AUTOSTART_ID=10460160173ff2b27151785420132590700000014790008
DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated

I'm starting to think something is not quite right in my configuration :)

Comment: you are not running a unity session,i.e. DESKTOP_SESSION=ubuntu  That should say "DESKTOP_SESSION=unity" Did you reboot yet after installing unity?? Then at greeter click on cog wheel > unity

Comment: @doug I think you were right, but I had rebooted several times already. What finally "fixed" it was choosing "Unity" on the cog wheel as you pointed out. With this, unity settings and unity-tweak-tool started working just fine. I' m removing this question since it seems there was something really missconfigured on my setup.

Comment: For the best unity experience in 17.10/18.04 one should switch to lightdm vs. gdm3.  There are also a few minor issues in the unity session, for 18.04 there will be at least 2 ppa's (one mine) to help deal with these..

Comment: Mr. Pumba, I  don't think you can remove a question with a bounty on it. Perhaps we should encourage @doug to write an answer which you can accept?

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Sure! I would be glad to accept an answer from doug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing & using a unity session in 17.10

This is generally quite simple, just go

`sudo apt install unity`

When done you *must reboot*, when back at the login screen click on little cog wheel to dropdown session choices & choose unity.

If auto logging in then after the reboot just log out, at the login screen expose the dropdown & choose unity.

Once chosen unity will then become your default login.

To get the best unity session experience one should use lightdm instead of gdm3, to do that simply

`sudo apt install lightdm`

At the conf prompt choose lightdm, reboot.

If not intending to use gnome-shell after switching to lightdm  feel free to remove gdm3 & gnome-shell, i.e. `sudo apt purge gdm3 gnome-shell`

There are some minor issues, most will be fixed or worked around for 18.04 but not for 17.10. As one example alt+print will not work to screenshot a window. The current workaround is this, (I've 'fixed' it in 18.04 via compiz & gnome-settings-daemon but hoping for more direct fix) -

```
press and hold Print Screen
press and hold Alt
release Print Screen (and then Alt)
```

Also if not getting onscreen notifications make sure notify-osd is installed,

`sudo apt install notify-osd`

Comment: added something about the notify-osd package as not sure it's included in 17.10, maybe not..